# Initializing cv::Mat with data doesn't work

Tags: c++, opencv

Following [this example](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/opencv-2.4.10-docs/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#creating-a-mat-object-explicitly) I tried to initialize an openCV `Mat` with the following values:

```
cv::Mat image = (cv::Mat_<int>(3,3) << 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0);
```

However, my IDE complains with

```
Binary operator '<<' can't be applied to the expressions of type 'cv::Mat_<int>' and 'int'
```

and when compiling I get

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (Unsupported combination of source format (=4), and buffer format (=5)) in getLinearRowFilter, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/filter.cpp, line 2857
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/filter.cpp:2857: error: (-213) Unsupported combination of source format (=4), and buffer format (=5) in function getLinearRowFilter
```

I used openCV for Python for quite a while now, but I'm completely lost using it with C++.

Comment: The error is not related with the code you posted. Post the relevant code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to apply a function (or a filter) that uses `getLinearRowFilter()` (such as `Sobel` and others) and you are using a combination of types (input and output) that is not allowed.

You can check the allowed combinations [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/filter.cpp#L3596), where `sdepth` is the depth of the source (`input`) and `ddepth` is the depth of the destination (`output`):

```
// these are allowed, otherwise the error will be thrown
if( sdepth == CV_8U && ddepth == CV_32S )
if( sdepth == CV_8U && ddepth == CV_32F )
if( sdepth == CV_8U && ddepth == CV_64F )
if( sdepth == CV_16U && ddepth == CV_32F )
if( sdepth == CV_16U && ddepth == CV_64F )
if( sdepth == CV_16S && ddepth == CV_32F )
if( sdepth == CV_16S && ddepth == CV_64F )
if( sdepth == CV_32F && ddepth == CV_32F )
if( sdepth == CV_32F && ddepth == CV_64F )
if( sdepth == CV_64F && ddepth == CV_64F )
```

Based on the error, you are probably using a `CV_32S` ([=4](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/904381c602043270fc864b29dd4749c9c75effbd/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L71)) input and a `CV_32F` ([=5](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/904381c602043270fc864b29dd4749c9c75effbd/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L72)) output. Basically, you cannot use `CV_32S` (a `Mat_<int>`) as input in function that uses `getLinearRowFilter()`.

To solve this, you can convert the input before using it. For example:

```
cv::Mat1i image = ...; // suppose this is your input (CV_32S == Mat_<int>)
cv::Mat1f output = ...; // suppose this is your output (CV_32F == Mat_<float>)

image.convertTo(image, CV_32F); // add this line right before the call
call_to_filter(image, output, ...); // your function (or filter) call
// e.g.: cv::Sobel(image, output, ...) will throw this error without convertion
```

Note: the information is inaccurate because not all relevant code is in the question.